# What is wrong with my Dijkstra algorithm for undirected graph?

Tags: python, dijkstra

Undirected graph dijkstra algorithm. Given start node, return a table mapping the shortest path from A to each node and its value.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def dijkstra(edges, start):

    graph = {}
    for (x, y, z) in edges:
        # A: [('B', 6)]
        graph[x] = graph.get(x, []) + [(y, z)]
        graph[y] = graph.get(y, []) + [(x, z)] # undirected graph
    
    
    table = {}
    for v in graph:
        table[v] = (float("inf"), None) # inf, no previous node
    table[start] = (0, None)
    stack = [(0, start)]
    
    visited = []
    while(stack != []):
        fill, node = heappop(stack)
        w = table[node][0]
        if(node in visited):
            continue
    
        visited.append(node)
        for (v, weight) in graph[node]:
            
            
            cur_weight, prev = table[v]
            if(cur_weight > weight + w):
                table[v] = (weight + w, node)
                
            cur_weight, prev = table[v]   
            heappush(stack, (cur_weight, v))
            
    return table           

edges = [['A', 'C', 1], ['C', 'E', 1], ['E', 'B', 1], ['A', 'B', 10]]
    
print(dijkstra(edges, 'A')) # outputs the correct table
```

the output is correct above for the table but for extemely large output like (n = 5000) it seems to fail and im unsure why?

Comment: Fail in what way? Incorrect result? Error message? Infinite loop?

Comment: incorrect result

Comment: If a node is in your "visited" list, you immediately stop looking.  For a large graph, it's quite possible that the shortest route from A to B might be A->C->E->B, but you wouldn't find that because you already visited B.

Comment: Thanks swapped stack with min heap and all test cases passed (errored before with min heap cus typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapped stack to minheap to prevent test cases like what was mentioned in the comments.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def dijkstra(edges, start):

    graph = {}
    for (x, y, z) in edges:
        # A: [('B', 6)]
        graph[x] = graph.get(x, []) + [(y, z)]
        graph[y] = graph.get(y, []) + [(x, z)] # undirected graph
    
    
    table = {}
    for v in graph:
        table[v] = (float("inf"), None) # inf, no previous node
    table[start] = (0, None)
    stack = [(0, start)]
    
    visited = set()
    while(stack != []):
        w, node = heappop(stack)
        if(node in visited):
            continue
    
        visited.add(node)
        for (v, weight) in graph[node]:
            
            
            cur_weight, prev = table[v]
            if(cur_weight > weight + w):
                table[v] = (weight + w, node)          
                heappush(stack, (weight + w, v))
            
    return table
```

Edit: Optimized it based on comments below

Comment: I'd recommend making `visited` a set, and to indent the last two lines `cur_weight, prev = table[v]; heappush(stack, (cur_weight, v))`, since `node in visited` takes `O(n)` for lists, and you only need to update the heap when a weight changes